# Create a scanning app to send to sheets to keep up with attendance daily and do all of this without me messing with it after it is created

Tags: google-apps-script

I'm trying to create an attendance program using the app scan to sheets. I have the Master List created with bar-codes and already have it comparing duplicates. I need to run triggers such that it updates daily at 9 am and it puts the new attendance in a new column with the new date. I need it to do all of this without my having to do anything but scan. It has to refresh daily at that time and essentially take attendance and keep track everyday. Is this possible?

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. Are you familiar with [time-driven triggers](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers/installable#time-driven_triggers)?

Comment: Could you clarify what you want?
Do you want a trigger to set all non-scanned entries as absent? Do you need to change the format from the scanned data to some specific output?

Please add more details to you question.